# carousel like with css, overflow-x (horizontal only)

Tags: html, image, css, carousel

I have an `overflow-x:scroll` and `overflow-y:hidden`. I have images, but when I'm trying to make it only scroll horizontally, it doesn't work? When I highlight the images and drag the highlight downwards, its scrolls down vertically.

```
#contents
{
margin:0 auto;
text-align:center;
width:1200px;
clear:both;
}

#image_contents
{
float:left;
height: 208px;
overflow-x:scroll;
overflow-y:hidden;
margin:0 auto;
}

.images 
{
float:left;
margin:2px;
background:#000;    
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
display:inline-block;
}

<div id="contents">
<div id="image_contents">

    <div class="images">
        <img src="1.jpg"/>
    </div>

    <div class="images">
         <img src="2.jpg"/>
    </div>

    <div class="images">
          <img src="3.jpg"/>
    </div>

    <!-- and so forth !->
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this, to my knowledge, would be to create another div inside the `image_contents` div. Then give this div the width of all the images (with JavaScript if necessary).

Another solution would be to use `display:table-cell` on the images inside another div with `display:table-row`.

Or (dare I say it) use a `table`.